# multilevel metanalysis with two outcomes

Tags: multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

I'm investigating the effect of an evaluative learning paradigm that uses the self on implicit and explicit attitude change and identification. This includes only studies we've conducted in our lab throughout the last 5 years.

- OUTCOMES: My metanalysis includes 53 studies. Among them 52 have both implicit and explicit attitude as outcome measure and, out of them, 14 studies also have a measure of identification. For all the measures, the effect sizes are based on mean differences between an experimental and a control condition. Please note that since I've all the datasets, I have information about the correlation between measures.
- SUBGROUPS: For most of the 53 study, I am able to distinguish among three independent subgroups of participants based on their memory performance throughout the study. We consider the memory of what has been done in the paradigm as a prerequisite for the effect to occur, Therefore, for each study we have participants with correct vs. incorrect vs. no memory of what they did in the task.
- MODERATORS: I've also a a list of moderators variable that I coded for each study (e.g., type of stimuli used, number of trials, proportion of female,...).

I've run three independent metanalyses for each outcome measures, and for each outcomes I've run three separate metanalyses based on the memory subgroups, modeling the role of the moderators in each of them. 
Reviewers would like me to run a multilevel multivariate metanalysis that would simultaneously account for the effect on the three different outcomes on the three subgroups and that would take care of intercorrelations among the coded moderators.

Do you have any suggestion on what is the best approach to meet their request?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the covariance matrix for the outcomes you should be able to do this in standard software. If you are using R I would suggest looking at Wolfgang Viechtbauer's examples on his website [here](http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/analyses) and looking for the section on multivariate analyses. I think the Berkey example is the closest to what you want to do. I would include the subgroups as another moderator variable and possibly add their interaction with your other moderators if that makes scientific sense. If you do not use R then the references he cites may well be helpful to you. I do not use Stata myself but I believe the Ian White has provided a mvmeta command which may work for you.